# Lebesgue Outer Measure is not Finitely Additive.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure, borel-measures

We know that Lebesgue Outer Measure is countably sub-additive. It is not even finitely additive. I am trying to find two sets of real numbers which are disjoint and yet $\mu ^*(A\cup B) = \mu^*(A) +\mu^*(B)$ doesn't hold.

Comment: It's additive on all measurable sets, by definition of measurable. So you need to use nonmeasurable sets.